# Sequelize default query about set time zone and client_min_messages

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a question about the query:

`SET client_min_messages TO warning;SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '+00:00' HOUR TO MINUTE;`

When I executing query in postgres: `select query from pg_stat_activity` I often see this query before executing my defined queries. I would like to disable the query. My columns have a timestamp with timezone but my default timezone is UTC. What can I do to remove it? Does it affect performance?

Answer (score 5):

`SET` is for setting runtime parameters, not querying the database. I could not even run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with `SET`; based on the programmatic complexity, would expect the times to resemble the shortest of queries. I doubt it affects performance **meaningfully**, but sure, a few bytes are being passed and parsed.

Those commands come from Sequelize's [connection-manager.js](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/fbd19d986170ad1edeeba123a0730854824aa515/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js). They are generated when initiating a connection, by

```js
if (this.sequelize.options.clientMinMessages !== false) {
  query += `SET client_min_messages TO ${this.sequelize.options.clientMinMessages};`;
}

if (!this.sequelize.config.keepDefaultTimezone) {
  const isZone = !!moment.tz.zone(this.sequelize.options.timezone);
  if (isZone) {
    query += `SET TIME ZONE '${this.sequelize.options.timezone}';`;
  } else {
    query += `SET TIME ZONE INTERVAL '${this.sequelize.options.timezone}' HOUR TO MINUTE;`;
  }
}
```

So, you could call `new Sequelize()` with  `clientMinMessages: false, keepDefaultTimezone: true` in the options object
([clientMinMessages here](https://sequelize.org/master/file/lib/sequelize.js.html); keepDefaultTimezone is less documented).

I have not profiled these. With a UTC timezone already set, keepDefaultTimezone seems safe. Note that if Sequelize does not set the postgres `client_min_messages` to `WARNING`, postgres may default to the slightly lower notification threshold of `NOTICE` and send some extra messages back to Sequelize. Whether any of these tweaks are worth pursuing will depend on your system.